# Time scale axis ticks positions

Tags: d3.js

I can't figure out why second last tick in not equally spaced [`In This Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/KWRxW/2221/)? I am using `d3 time scale`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the space between the "Mon 26" tick and the unlabeled tick, it's because the last tick just represents the end of the axis, not another whole day. Since you don't have any data after the 26th, d3 didn't make the axis extend a full additional day.

This last tick is called an outer tick. If you want to get rid of it, you can set its size to 0: `axis.outerTickSize(0)`

Comment: Is there a way to equally divide the space between "Mon 26 tick" and last tick among all the ticks. So that "Mon 26" tick map to axis last tick